# SOLVED - Python SQLite Update Using variable entries and multiples conditions

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I am new to database management and I want to update my SQLite database when two conditions match, but my Python code below is returning the error:

```
try:
    cursor.execute("UPDATE mytable SET field1 = ?,  field2 = ?, field3 = ?, field4 = ? WHERE field5 = ? AND field6 = ?;", var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6)
except Exception as e:
    Logging.Error("Exception "+str(e))
```

Error:

> Exception execute expected at most 2 arguments, got 7

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: What does the documentation say about the `execute` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `execute` functions takes 2 parameters: A string (the SQL statement) and a **tuple** of values. What you pass in is a string and 6 other values. You need to put the last 6 values in a tuple:

```py
cursor.execute(
    "UPDATE mytable SET field1 = ?,  field2 = ?, field3 = ?, field4 = ?"
    " WHERE field5 = ? AND field6 = ?;",
    (var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6),
)
```